# Integrating matlab with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matlab

Is it possible to have a interface from visual studio which can call a matlab file(code) and run it .

I basically want a .exe file which have GUI from VS and code from matlab.
Thanks

Comment: It is not possible. VS can not execute/debug matlab code. Those are two different animals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works if you're building a GUI and integrate it in a `.mex` file:
You can call matlab functions or user-defined functions with `mexCallMATLAB` from `mex.h`:
[mexCallMATLAB](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html?searchHighlight=mexcallmatlab)

If you're building a standalone program in C/C++ (that results in a `.exe` file) then there's something called `Matlab Engine` which you can call to execute `Matlab` code. Take a look here to read more about this interface [Matlab engine](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-matlab-engine.html). It's basically a C library that allows you to call `Matlab`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is, but I'm still pretty sure the answer is "No".

If you've built a user-interface using one of the visual studio languages (eg C#, VB.NET etc), and you want that interface to call a matlab script you have two options I am aware of:

1) Buy the matlab .NET interface from Mathworks. I'm not exactly sure how this works, since it costs lots of money and I don't have it.

2) Buy the matlab compiler (which also costs lots of money) and "compile" up your matlab code into an executable. Then call that executable from your .NET language of choice through the command line. The problem with this approach is that the only way to pass data into your matlab script is through the call to the script from the command line. The usual workaround is to pass through the location of a txt or csv file in the call from the command line, and then have the first portion of your matlab script devoted to retrieving the data from this txt or csv file. Another problem with this approach is that if you want to call lots of matlab scripts, it will take you a long time, because each time you call a "compiled" matlab script, in the background, you are actually creating a new instance of all the matlab runtime libraries through a beast called the matlab compiler runtime. This is why I say "compiled" - because it still interprets at runtime, so it isn't really compiled.

**EDIT**

To call a matlab script using VB.NET, you might try:

```
    '#Get the matlab executable info
    Dim MatlabStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    MatlabStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    MatlabStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
    MatlabStartInfo.Arguments = "/C " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _ 
    & "C:\Path\To\Matlab\Script\Matlab_Script.exe " & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) _
    & MatlabScriptInputArgument & Chr(34) & Chr(34)

    '#Run the matlab executable
    Using MatlabProcess As Process = New Process
        MatlabProcess.StartInfo = MatlabStartInfo
        MatlabProcess.Start()
        MatlabProcess.WaitForExit()
    End Using
```

where MatlabScriptInputArgument is a string containing the argument to your matlab function (the above code assumes only one input).

Comment: So can you tell me what is the best way to create a good GUI for matlab code ?? , as the GUI matlab provides is very low level

Comment: @Atish A good GUI is a good GUI, whether it is designed to run matlab code or for any other task. The subject of how to build a good GUI is very different from your original question and, honestly, not something that can be easily answered in a single stack-overflow post. It is a BIG topic. If you want to know how to call a matlab script from a VS GUI, well, I've attached some VB.NET code to my answer above that should get you started.

Comment: @Atish Also, if you feel that I have answered your initial question, then please mark my response answered by clicking the tick mark next to my response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not Visual Studio, but there is a [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) MatLab [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gimly81.matlab).